# How much performance improvement from Netty 3.5.x to Netty 4

Tags: netty

How much performance improvement from Netty 3.5.x to Netty 4? Are there some data?

Answer (score 4):

Not much improvement as of this moment.  It has significantly less GC overhead though.  Once buffer pooling is implemented, I believe throughput will also get better.  For now, throughput gain is around 5~10%, but YMMV.